# when push array in select2 jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

In select2

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 180; i++) {
    eyeaxisdropdown.push({ "id": i, "text": i});
}
$(".eyeax").select2({placeholder:'Select',data:eyeaxisdropdown});`
```

find javascript runtime error-

```
var match=text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) is not defined
```

how to resolve this bug?

Answer (score 0):

i see some strange chars in your code, here the last char:

```
$(".eyeax").select2({placeholder:'Select',data:eyeaxisdropdown});`
```

and here the last char was supposed to be a semmicolon not a comma:

```
var match=text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()),
```

you wrote "how to resolve this bug"...which bug? i just see you posted some javascript jquery code but neither a bug nor a bug description.